# list of mixed string and int types

Tags: c#

I am trying to have a list of generic types (actually I need only string and int). Both objects have Name (string) but Value is different (int or string)

```
public class Setting
{    
    public string Name { get; set; }   
}

public class Setting<T> : Setting
{
    public T Value { get; set; }

    public Type Type
    {
        get
        {
            return typeof(T);
        }
    }    
}
```

The list as follows:

```
List<Setting> list = new List<Setting>();
list.Add(new Setting<int> { Name = "one", Value = 10 } );
list.Add(new Setting<string> { Name = "two", Value = "string value" });
```

However, when I try to get the Value it is non existing.

```
list[0].Value ????
```

Can this be done?

EDIT:

Surprisingly how simple it was (compared to generics, interfaces), thank @Patrick Hofman for "object" hint.

```
    public class Settings
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public object Value { get; set; }
    }

Fields = new List<Settings>{
                        new Settings { Name = "Three", Value = "Three_value" },
                        new Settings{ Name = "Four", Value = 22 },
                        new Settings { Name = "Two", Value = "22" }
                    }
```

Works like a charm.

Comment: No it can´t be done. First off: generics are supposed to work on *any* type, not just on `string` and `int`. Second: you should ask yourself, what those types have in common. Is there anything which can be done with both, strings *and* ints? From my perspective not much. Don´t put instances of types that don´t have anything in common into one single un-generic list. Even if you could do this, what type would you expect when you write `list[0]`? The compiler surely can only provide `Setting`, but you´ll never know if it is actually a `Setting<string>` or a `Setting<int>`.

Comment: C# does not support this idiom well as it has no native support for sum types (AKA [discriminated unions](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/113)). The best you can get is working through `object`. (Or use a [library](https://github.com/mcintyre321/OneOf), but for simple use cases it's overkill.)

Comment: Your list is typed against `Setting`, which doesn't have a `Value` property.

Comment: Another idea would be to have interface, e.g. `IValue`, which define `object Value` and having `Setting<T>` implement it, but then you have `List<IValue>` and can't call methods of `Setting` without casting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not the most elegant solution, but it will work:

```
public class Setting
{

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public object Value { get; protected set; }
}

public class Setting<T> : Setting
{
    public new T Value { get { return (T)base.Value; } set { base.Value = value; } }

    public Type Type
    {
        get
        {
            return typeof(T);
        }
    }
}
```

Effectively you are storing the value in the base class, and you cast it in the derived class.

I would advocate to check your design, and if you really need generics here. As shown, this defeats the generics purpose.

Comment: I personally like this solution and have used it often when not forcing a class to be generic but rather a method. This guarantees type safety when invoking with more flexibility.

Comment: @Patrick Hofman just thanks!